# Does English have an expression like "nth day"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, count

In my native language, if today is 1st and Sunday and we want to refer to the next Sunday (on 8th) then we may say the "today's eighth day" or just "8th day". For example if you're asking when does the festival begin? Someone may reply: 8th day. Obviously the count 8 includes today. On the other hand if we excluded today then it'd have been the 7th day from today.

Does English have an expression like that? If so today is Sunday and one wants to refer to Tuesday, is it called 2nd day from today or 3rd day from today?

Comment: We typically say, "*n* **days** from today".  And since "1 day from today" can't mean today (that would be 0 days from today) we'd say "2 days from now" or "2 days from today" to mean Tuesday if today was Sunday.

Comment: I'm not sure. We could say, "I'll meet you three days from now"  or "I'll meet you in three days time" Is that what you mean?

Comment: So if you plan to see someone tomorrow, you say you'll see them in two days not one? English doesn't normally work that way, although this is the confusion that led to penal sentences of a year and a day. Cultural differences are common here; for example in English two weeks is a fortnight (14 days) yet in Spanish it is a quincena (15 days) for the same period.

Comment: We can also just use the absolute dates:  "I'll meet you on the 8th" which refers to the day of the month. @Lavya, your example is a little ambiguous.  if today was July 16th and a Sunday and you wanted to meet someone on Tuesday the 18th would you say "the 18th day from today" or would you say, "the 2nd day from today" or would you say, "the 3rd day from today"?

Comment: If you were going to meet someone on Tuesday, I'd just say "I'll meet you on Tuesday".

Comment: @Jim "the 3rd day from today". Although, thinking again, the expression will literally translate closer  to "today's nth day" and "nth day from today". I see the same day of the next week being referred to as something like "today's 8th day". I'll modify the expression in the question. we have particular terms for tomorrow day after tomorrow and also the day after day after tomorrow so I don't see the numbers 1,2,3 used in this way.

Comment: @Catija Yes, we can use the absolute dates and days and we do that as well. But I'm thinking about expressions used in my village (in a developing country with pretty low literacy rate) and that may be a reason why this kind of relative expression is also very common.  Most people farm and I doubt most people even keep track of what "date" it is. And there are multiple systems of calendars used anyway. Edit: I see you just point out how one would do it in English. Fair enough, Although I'm still interested in knowing all kinds of relative/ordinal usage.

Comment: I think that what chasly said is the closest... "I'll meet you in three days" or "I'll see you in a week". That's all we've got. I've lived in a big city my entire life and being aware of the day of the week and the time is inherent in everything. Even when I forget what day it is, if I say "Um... Tuesday... when's that?" Someone would likely reply "It's Sunday, so, in two days".

Comment: You can say "on Tuesday", "next Tuesday", "a week from Tuesday", "two weeks from Tuesday". "Three days from now" is perfectly grammatical, but people are more likely to use the days of the week.

Comment: @jim  typo in my comment above: the expression will literally translate closer to "today's nth day" and *not* "nth day from today".

Comment: @tchrist "So if you plan to see someone tomorrow, you say you'll see them in two days not one?" Not "in two days" but  "second day". Although as I wrote we have specific names for tomorrow and the next two days so this is mostly used for larger numbers, most commonly for "8th day" when referring to the same day of the next week.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yes I want to know about the similar expressions used in English. I think I have to stop and think for a moment when someone refers to nth day kinds of expressions in any language to avoid making one-off kinds of errors so I want to be clear how it is in different languages. You're right, "see you in n day" seems to be the most common in English with counting starting with 1 meaning the next day.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks! That seems to be the consistent pattern in English at least from the answers on this thread. In One week = in 7 days = on next Sunday if today is Sunday.

Comment: @Lavya Same day in a week is 7 days for English speakers but 8 days for Spanish speakers.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks. So it's not only my native tongue then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments have given you all the details of using numbers in precise ways.

My answer is going to give you the natural ways of talking about time (in terms of days) in English.  I wasn't sure if you are also interested in that, but in case you are, here goes.

Mostly we use the name of the day of the week, but we can also say tomorrow, day after tomorrow, yesterday and day before yesterday; and we can also use the date, e.g. We decided to meet on the 11th or on August 11th.

The most common chunks of time are a week, 10 days, two weeks, and month.  If you don't mind being a little vague, a couple of days or a few days -- I would interpret those as being two or three, possibly four.

The rhythm of the work week and then the weekend give us very strong signposts -- this must be different from a farming village.  So you'll hear early next week, the beginning of the week, the middle of the week, the end of the week, close to the weekend, etc.

Your bookclub might meet on the second Tuesday of the month.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the modern work culture of weekdays-weekend makes the use of "day" (as in Monday Tuesday) as well as dates  more prevalent than old style agrarian villages, where the emphasis might be on the time period.

Comment: the closest example I can think of is **fortnight** which is a two week period.

Comment: @Yeshe Please see my paragraph about the common chunks of time.

Comment: Yes, you alluded to it while I provided an actual word.I did not obelize your answer (it is quite good) I merely expanded upon it with an example such as **overmorrow**, the word for the day after tomorrow.

Comment: @Yeshe Sorry, in my experience (mostly American English), *fortnight* isn't very common; *overmorrow* is something I have never heard!  And *obelize* I'm going to have to look up in a dictionary!  ----  Just curious, what flavor of English do you speak, or what region of the world are you from?

Comment: I am from Texas but I was raised primarily by my grandparents. One of whom was a librarian and I was raised in a somewhat reclusive nature with many a dusty tome. I socialized far more with old books than with people. My vernacular has been a prior point of contention with my "peers".

Comment: @Yeshe, Thanks, that's interesting, and it helps me understand where *overmorrow* came from.  The dusty "relatives".